# Задача составления расписания. Алгоритм перебора

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Необходимо написать программу составления расписания. Из-за проблем внешних не выйдет погрузиться в поиск информации.

Для упрощения решил сделать решение простым перебором, но не получается составить алгоритм хотя бы.

Составитель расписания пишется на Windows Forms (C#). Это не совсем классическое приложение-составитель. Действующие лица в нём - лаборанты высших учебных заведений. Соответственно есть 2 сетки занятости. Одна для аудиторий, с выбором конкретных пар на неделе. Другая аналогичная для лаборантов, но с добавлением поля ввода рабочих ставок в минутах (для упрощения).
[image: Внешний вид программы]
P.S.:
Знаю про существование генетического алгоритма, но его суть не понял и не знаю как с ним работать.

Comment: Как эта фигня называется, с обводкой которая и слева сверху надпись написана

Comment: Ничего не понял, в чем вопрос то?

Comment: подсказать алгоритм составления расписания простым перебором

Comment: Модель данных тоже надо по скриншотам угадать?

Comment: Ну, да. Изменил. Это кортежи, их нельзя изменить, поэтому кортежи лаборантов переходят в отдельный класс, где менять данные уже можно.